# Julia: Sort matrix by rows using custom comparator

Tags: arrays, sorting, julia

I have the following two dimensional Array:

```
[120 320;
150 270;
230 250]
```

the rows of which I want to sort with regards to the second element in each row. I could not find anyway to do that using Julia's `Base.sort()`. Is it is possible to achieve this using `Base.sort()` or are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `sortslices` for this:

```
julia> x = [120 320;
            150 270;
            230 250]
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 120  320
 150  270
 230  250

julia> sortslices(x, dims=1, by= x->x[2])
3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 230  250
 150  270
 120  320
```